# device that shoots audio which can only be heared by the target

Tags: speakers

I'm sorry if this is not the correct site for this question; I just found this to be the most pertinent site under the technology tag.

Is there (or is it possible to create) a device that shoots audio over a medium distance (say 50 feet) which can only be heared by one person. Similar to how a laser focuses and radiates a beam of photons in a straight line, the device would vibrate molecules in a narrow beam in the direction pointed. I would imagine that it would have some form of parabolic speaker.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, and these already exist in various forms, from sound weapons to localised 'personal' audio devices.

The vast majority use a parabolic reflector, as you correctly surmised. Some [background here](http://illumin.usc.edu/105/directional-audio/).

But [this one](http://mashable.com/2012/03/22/soundlazer-kickstarter-speaker/#4svPq2E8WPqs) uses interesting technology with an array of Ultrasonic speakers which provide interference at the target which is within audible frequencies.

Comment: Am I really the only one who finds this ultrasonic technique scary?

Comment: It's the high amplitude that's really scary - yes